# Residue of $\sin (1/z)$ in $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series, singularity

> Find the residue of $$f(z)=\sin(1/z)$$ in its singularity point.

**My attempt:**
I have 2 different answers so my question is: where is my mistake in one of the answers?

**Answer 1:**
$$\nexists \lim_{z\to 0}f(z)
\\ \lim_{z\to0}f(z)\cdot z=\lim_{z\to0}\sin(1/z)/(1/z)$$ But
$$
|{\sin(1/z)\over 1/z}|\leq|{1\over (1/z)}|=|z|\to0
$$
Thus $$\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)\cdot z=0$$Then $z=0$ is a simple pole and $\operatorname{Res}(f,0)=0$.

**Answer 2:**

In the Laurent expansion of $f$ around $z=0$, the coefficient $c_{-1}$ equals $1$, thus the residue equals $1$.

Comment: Just adding a small remark: if z=0 is a simple pole of f(z), then the residue there cannot be zero

Comment: Why is that? @zokomoko

Comment: Because the residue of f(z) at zero (by definition) is the coeffcient of 1/z in the laurent expansion of f(z) around 0. Since z=0 is a simple pole of f(z) then (according to one of the equivalent definitions of a pole of order m, here m=1) the most negative power in the above mentioned laurent expansion is -1 and the coefficient of z^(-1) is nonzero (Otherwise, z=0 would have been a removeable singularity)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first answer is wrong. It is false that$$(\forall z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}):\left\lvert\sin\left(\frac1z\right)\right\rvert\leqslant1.$$In fact$$\lim_{t\to0^+}\left\lvert\sin\left(\frac it\right)\right\rvert=\infty.$$